# Flutter Drawer overflow

Tags: flutter, navigation-drawer

I am trying to achieve the follow Drawer display on my Flutter app. I have a problem to paint the X close icon, which is outside of the drawer. Is there are easy way to draw that X that is out of drawer layout? Please note that drawer content itself can have many rows (scrollable.)

[image: Desired Drawer layout]

So far i come to following solution:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class tempDrawer extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return
      Container(
          width: 250,

          child:Drawer(child:
          SafeArea(child:Container(
            //width: 300,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  gradient: LinearGradient(
                    begin: Alignment.topCenter,
                    end: FractionalOffset.bottomCenter,
                    colors: [Color(0xffa4151a), Color(0xffe34b3d)],
                    stops: [0, 1],
                  )),
              child: ListView(
                padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Row(mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                      children: [
                        Container(width:70,child:ClipOval(child: Image(
                          image: AssetImage("images/face.png"),
                          fit: BoxFit.cover,
                          height: 70,
                          width: 70,
                        ))),
                        Container(width: 16,),
                        Container(width: 129,child:Text("Alex assdsddff",overflow: TextOverflow.clip, style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),)),
                        ClipOval(
                            child:Container(
                                decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Color(0xffa4151a)),
                                width: 50,
                                child:
                                Container(child: Icon(Icons.close,size: 40,color: Colors.white,)))),
                      ]),
                  Divider(color: Colors.white,indent: 20,endIndent: 20,),
                  Row(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Icon(Icons.home_outlined,color: Colors.white,),
                      Padding(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 8.0),
                        child: Text("HOME", style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),),
                      )
                    ],
                  ),

                ],
              )),
          )
          ));
  }
}
```

Which give me result that i need, but i have an "overflow" message at a place where my icon is located. Is there any more correct way to place the close icon or at least somehow get rid of overflow message per specific widget?

[image: Output result]

Comment: can you include the full drawer widget?

Comment: I include it initially, but make slight edit for it to display more good.

Comment: From your question code-snippet it doesn't include the behavior that you want it might be resolution issue , can you include the test device resolution as well, does my answer satisfy your question?

Comment: The bottom picture is what displayed on my device. In base i have a drawer with width of 250. then inside drawer i have a user picture with 70 width, then 16 of free space, then 129 for text. It give me total 215 width. Then i place my X with 50 width. So 35 of it still on drawer and 15 is outside. That is how is really should be. But i want to get rid of that warning overflow message.

Comment: Try flutter clean and rebuild the app,  your question widget's `x` is inside the Drawer.

Comment: I not sure what you mean. I have two test devices and both show X outside (which it should be)

Comment: Can you recheck the widget

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You use `Stack` to divide Drawer in two part and get the UI.   An easier way will be using `transform`.

Remove `ClipOval` widget and use `shape: BoxShape.circle` on `Container`.

```dart
class tempDrawer extends StatelessWidget {
  final drawerWidth = 250.0;
  final double iconButtonSize = 50;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SizedBox(
      width: drawerWidth + iconButtonSize * .5, // we want half outside
      child: Theme(
        // make transparent drawer
        data: Theme.of(context).copyWith(
          canvasColor: Colors.white.withOpacity(0),
        ),
        child: Drawer(
          child: Stack(
            children: [
              Container(
                  width: drawerWidth,
                  decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                    gradient: LinearGradient(
                      begin: Alignment.topCenter,
                      end: FractionalOffset.bottomCenter,
                      colors: [Color(0xffa4151a), Color(0xffe34b3d)],
                      stops: [0, 1],
                    ),
                  ),
                  child: ListView(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Row(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                          children: [
                            Container(
                              width: 70,
                              color: Colors.green,
                              // child: ClipOval(
                              // child: Image(
                              //   image: AssetImage("images/face.png"),
                              //   fit: BoxFit.cover,
                              //   height: 70,
                              //   width: 70,
                              //   //   ),
                              // ),
                            ),
                            const SizedBox(
                              width: 16,
                            ),
                            SizedBox(
                              // remove  img+space width
                              width: drawerWidth - 70 - 16,
                              child: const Text(
                                "Alex assdsddff",
                                overflow: TextOverflow.clip,
                                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ]),
                      Divider(
                        color: Colors.white,
                        indent: 20,
                        endIndent: 20,
                      ),
                      Row(
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Icon(
                            Icons.home_outlined,
                            color: Colors.white,
                          ),
                          Padding(
                            padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 8.0),
                            child: Text(
                              "HOME",
                              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                            ),
                          )
                        ],
                      ),
                    ],
                  )),
              Positioned(
                top: 20,
                right: 0,
                child: Container(
                  alignment: Alignment.center,
                  decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                    color: Colors.pink,
                    shape: BoxShape.circle,
                  ),
                  width: iconButtonSize,
                  height: iconButtonSize,
                  child: GestureDetector(
                    onTap: () {
                      print("close");
                    },
                    child: const Icon(
                      Icons.close,
                      size: 40,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[image]

You can use `Drawer:elevation` to handle shade.

Comment: I am not the person who down vote, but your solution display same Overflow warning, when i change ClipOval to Container.

Comment: Can you include the exact text and widget you've used that will reproduce the same issue,

Comment: I think i get what you want to tell me.  I need to experiment with this transform.  It display outside and not give me overflow error. Need to see how it will work with onTap included. I will back to you tomorrow. Thank you for your help

Comment: I make that to look like following code, it display the X correctly now, but i can not get it to react to onTap when clicking to part of X that is outside. Since that still close drawer when i click outside and that is what i really need its fine. But still would like to know how properly handle click on that transformed element.

Comment: I forgot about the click event. Seems like we need to use stack in this case. You can also check [this to know about it](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62499868/10157127)

Answer (score 0):

Try below code hope its helpful to you. add your container inside `Expanded` or `Flexible` Widget. refer Expanded [here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Expanded-class.html) and Flexible [here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Flexible-class.html)

```
     Expanded(
                      child: Container(
                        width: 99,
                        child: Text(
                          "Some user name",
                          overflow: TextOverflow.clip,
                          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
```

Your result screen-> [image]

Comment: I not need X to be inside red area, it should be half-outside of it. So right now X at correct position.

Comment: what do you exactly want?

Comment: I need to have layout i provided with X icon placed at position it already placed, but without overflow warning.